# Swaping out image sources while avoiding extra GET requests, maintaining support and semantics

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to swap out my image sources dependant on the window size and pixel density- To prevent mobiles loading extra large images while still serving full res images to things like retina macbooks with huge screens. 
I've got an img elemnt looking like this:

```
<img class="projectimg responsivize" src=mobile.jpg data-mobile-x2=mobile-retina.jpg data-tablet=tablet.jpg data-tablet-x2=tablet-retina.jpg data-full=desktop.jpg data-full-x2=desktop-retina.jpg   />
```

I'm using vanila javascript(don't want to wait for lidbaries to load) below(WIP, needs screen size testing, just swaps out for the full size image at the moment)

```
var toresponsive = document.getElementsByClassName("responsivize");
for (var i=toresponsive.length -1; i >= 0;i--){
  toresponsive[i].setAttribute('src',toresponsive[i].getAttribute('data-full'));
}
```

This is working fine- My question is about the placement- If I put it in the `head` then it runs before the browser can see the image tags. If I put it at the end of `body`, The browser GETs all the small image sources- doubling the number of http requests for non-mobile screens. 
Is there a way to have the browser not GET the images until the javascript has run, while leaving a values in the `src` attribute of the `img` tags so I have support for systems not running javascript?

Comment: I'm affraid you can't. If you want your code to run when DOM contains the img tags, well, the browser begins loading those images already. You may minimize the impact by leaving the smallest size, lowest quality images for the poor non javascript browsers.

Comment: @PA.Thanks, this was what I thought, and have done.